# Where to store RealTime Database Snapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a RealTime database structured in the follow way:

```
garage-x23df
    cars
        -LQ0aZ9IP5jCL9Qj5x4D
        -LQ0a_R1Oxh4KazLHVZb
        -LQ0ao2lvhdurSl8qaF1
        -LSsIrK0tziyiJLKfDX1
        ...
```

I want to manipulate this data in different activities (one activity to display a list of the cars, another activity to display the data of a specific car, another activity that manipulates a filtered list of cars and so on).

Should I get a new DataSnapshot in each activity or should I store the data locally once it has been fetched and send it between the activities (I have achieved this by building a serializable ArrayList from the DataSnapshot and I have been sending it via intents).

I have around 400 entries of cars, each one includes about 15 fields (Strings and Boolean only), but am expecting to scale this number.

I am afraid of performance issues when sending such a large ArrayList between activities, but on the other hand I think it is not efficient to fetch a DataSnapshot with each activity.

What is the best practice method to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: There is no singular correct answer for this. But if you [enable offline caching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence), the data will be loaded from the local cache for all activities but the first.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate Java class which can retrieve data from the database and all the get method whenever you want to retrieve an item. For example, suppose you have a child in your database called ‘mad’ with three other nodes under it, called jack, John and jimmy, each with different values, for instance jack has the string value ‘tick’, John has string value ‘young’ and jimmy has value ‘yipy’. Your class would look something like this

```
   public class Retrieve{
     private String Jack;
     private String Jimmy;
     private String John;
   public Retrieve (String Jack, String Jimmy, String John)
     Jack=jack;
     Jimmy=jimmy;
     John=john;
   public Retrieve(){}
   @PropertyName(“jack”)
   public String getJack(){return Jack;}
   @PropertyName(“jimmy”)
   public String getJimmy(){return Jimmy;}
   @PropertyName(“John”)
   public String getJohn(){return John;}
```

Then you can Retrieve them and set them in any part of your app using the same style of code. Let’s say for instance you want to set a value from jack to a text view in your main activity,

```
   ........
   @Override
   public void onDataChanged(@Nullable DataSnapshot datasnapshot){
   for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot. 
   getChildren()){
   if(snapshot!=null){
    Retrieve retrieve =snapshot.getValue(Retrieve.class);
    if(retrieve!=null){
    String no=retrieve.getJack();
    Dast.setText(no)
```

Comment: Creating a separate class only simplifies the coding process, yet I will still have to pull all the data from FireBase on each activity.  Or am I missing something?  Thanks!

Comment: If am getting you clearly, you want to download all the relevant data from firebase and store them in the app?